# Matching XElements in an XDocument against a list of names

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have loaded Xml similar to the following into an XDocument

```
<requestlist>
  <request name="Apple" jobtype="radio">
    <schedule intervalminutes="1440" daily="true" updateDateTime="2014-08-07T15:43:00Z">
      <channel>someData/channel>
      <signal>someData</readysignal>
      <frequency>someData</frequency>
    </schedule>
    <file>someData</file>
    <file>someData</file>
  </request>
  </requestlist>
```

I now want to add a second request that has some info from he first and deletes some unneeded elements e.g.

```
 <request name="newBanana">
    <schedule intervalminutes="1440" daily="true" updateDateTime="2014-08-07T15:43:00Z">
    </schedule>
    <file>someData</file>
</request>
```

Is there a simple way I can remove the elements using Linq by matching against a list
e.g.

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

XDocument configXml = XDocument.Parse(theXml)
var oldRequest = configXml.XPathSelectElement(@"/requestlist/request[@name=""Apple""]");

var nodesToRemove = new List<XName>() {"channel", "signal", "radio"};
var newRequest = oldRequest.Elements().Select(e => e.Name).Intersect(nodesToRemove); //OR something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your XPath stops at `<schedule>` element instead of `<request>` because you'll be removing child of `<schedule>` here :

```
var oldRequest = doc.XPathSelectElement(@"/requestlist/request[@name='Apple']/schedule");
```

Then yes, you can use simple LINQ to remove elements matched a name in list :

```
var nodesToRemove = new List<XName>() { "channel", "signal", "radio" };
oldRequest.Elements()
          .Where(o => nodesToRemove.Contains(o.Name))
          .Remove();
```